# I can no longer debug Office Add-in from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, office-js, office-addins

I have been working on an add-in for Excel. When I run my add-in from Visual Studio, it usually launches Excel, and adds a button the the ribbon which I use to open a task pane.

Now, when Excel launches, it immediately shows a task pane with the following error.

> ADD-IN ERROR
>
> This add-in is no longer available: add-ins inserted during
> development are only available during debugging from Visual Studio.
> Please open your project in Visual Studio and re-run your application,
> or deploy your add-in into a valid catalog and re-insert.

The suggestion in the error message is frustrating because it is telling me to do exactly what I am trying to do.

I have:

- Restarted my Computer
- Cleared the Office Cache
- Modified the version number in the manifest
- Validated the manifest
- Removed Task Pane Add-ins using the Document Inspector

My manifest has not changed at all since the plugin last worked. (save for my debugging attempts)

I am using Visual Studio 16.6.0 Preview 6.0, and Excel for Office 365 16.0.12527.20260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the source of the issue.

I had a `Start Document` specified in my Add-in project. When I switched the `Start Document` back to `[New Excel Workbook]`, my add-in started loading correctly.

I tried opening my document in Excel, and I saw that it was marked as Read-Only. It appears that Visual Studio cannot launch an Excel add-in with a read-only start document. I resaved my file, and set it back to being the `Start Document` of the add-in project. Now, everything has started working again.

Answer (score 0):

For future suffering devs: this error can also happen if you have an invalid manifest. For me, it was a description that was too long (the limit is really short!).

To find it, you might be able to run `npm run validate` if it's set up for you, if not that's a script that runs: `office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml`

Safe travels, future add-in devs